# How can I run a script as part of a Swift Package Manager build?

Tags: ios, swift-package-manager

I am converting existing iOS frameworks to modules using Swift Package Manager (SPM); in one case I have a script that was in the Build Phases of the original framework version, that I need to run as part of the new Swift Package Manager build process.

I have tried adding a Pre-action script to the Build portion of the scheme for the module in question (per Ben-xD's comment at https://forums.swift.org/t/how-to-run-a-build-phase-script-when-building-a-standalone-swift-package-in-xcode/40117/8, though his later comment indicates it doesn't work).  I found that approach does work *if* I build the module directly.  However, if the module is being built as a dependency of a client app or module (or even as a dependency of its unit tests) that script does not seem to get called.

I am currently relying on the Package.swift manifest file to manage all the module settings, and am using this within Xcode to build and test.

Is there a way to run scripts as part of an SPM module build, so that they will get run reliably, whether the module is built directly or indirectly as a dependency? (Possibly something that can be added to the Package.swift file?)

*Update*: I have done some additional searching, and came across this:
https://forums.swift.org/t/pitch-swiftpm-extensible-build-tools/44715/5
suggesting that it's not possible, but may be in the future.  Until then, wondering if there is any workaround to do something as simple as take a file that is autogenerated as part of the SPM build, but rename it before adding it to the resource bundle for the package.

Answer (score -4):

By the definition of Package in Swift, there is currently no Script-related definition.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32915275)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).