# Strip executableTargets in release mode with Swift Package Manager?

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I have a simple Swift executable:

```swift
let package = Package(
    name: "myproject",
    targets: [
        .executableTarget(
            name: "myproject"
        ),
    ]
)
```

When I build it, the executable size is 1.7mb. After using `strip`, though, a megabyte is removed.
Is there a way to do this automatically in release mode?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68565221/how-can-i-run-a-script-as-part-of-a-swift-package-manager-build